# Why does Gradle output checking (for UP-TO-DATE skipping) not consider additional 'bad' files in the output directory as a difference?

Tags: build, gradle

I'm going to use a simple task to illustrate my question. 
(My real task is a python script that generates images based on an input set of xml files and image files. The output of that task is a directory with different xml files and images.)

Anyways, consider this task:

```
task t {
    inputs.dir 'src'
    outputs.dir 'dst'

    doLast {
        copy {
            from 'src'
            into 'dst'
        }
    }
}
```

Place a file `foo.txt` into `src/`. Now run `gradle t`. Result: there's a new file `foo.txt` in `dst/`.

If I run `gradle t` again, it will say it's UP-TO-DATE and not run. Good.
Now, if I remove `dst/foo.txt`, it will run, correctly detecting that the destination has changed.

Also, if I edit the contents of `dst/foo.txt`, it recognizes the change. Good!

However, if I put an additional file inside of `dst`, e.g. `dst/badfile.txt`, it will not recognize this as a 'dirty' output directory.

Since I defined the output dir as a directory, and not a set of output files, I'd expect it to examine the whole state of the directory. Why does it not consider additional files to be a difference? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say for sure why this decision was made. Perhaps it was due to the need to support multiple tasks sharing the same output directory (as used to be the case for, say, `compileJava` and `processResources`).